# websocket handhsake exception: 200

Tags: spring-websocket

I am using springboot to setup my websocket endpoint and angularJs to connect to my endpoint. which i have done before and it worked fine that time. but now when i do it in new project. its giving me hand shake error. below is mycode:

**Websocket config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chatService").setAllowedOrigins("*").addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
    }
}
```

**angularJs code:**

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.225.133:9191/chatService');
//              console.log(socket);
                stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
                stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {

                    if(frame.command=="CONNECTED"){
                    //alert(frame);
                    //showLoader(false);
                        stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:9191/chat/messages', function(response) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
                             chat.gif=false;
                            console.log("data_json...");
                            if(data.to==$scope.admin.id)
                            $scope.getMessagesById(data.from,1);
                            else
                                $scope.getMessagesById(data.to,1);
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.myImgs=null;


                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        var r = confirm("Could not connect! Retry?");
                        if (r == true) {
                            connect();
                        } 
                    }

                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my project there was a client forward controller. disabling that fixed the issue.